# Git submodule, add only ignored directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

Say I have the following structure:

```
Foo
  |-- Bar 1 (git repo)
       |-- Folder 1
       |-- Folder 2
  |-- Bar 2 (git repo)
       |-- Folder 1
       |-- Folder 2
```

where Bar 1 and Bar 2 are the *same* cloned git repo (say code for a project) and such that Folder 2 is in .gitignore for both directories. (So both Bar 1 and Bar 2 ignore Folder 2), but Folder 1 is actually in the "Bar" repo itself.

What I want to do is create a new repository at the folder Foo which keeps track of the changes in all of the Folder 2s. (aka the Folders which are not in the Bar 1/2 repos)

I keep trying to add submodules and stuff like that, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want/need. (I don't know much about submodules and they're a little confusing when you're dealing with already existing content) Anyone know how to do this or can point me to a guide that shows how to make submodules work other than the basic guides?

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is create a new repository at the folder Foo

That new repository does not have to be at the folder Foo.
A submodule is a way to import a *remote* repository reference into your current repository.

So ideally, you define Folder2 outside of Foo and push it to its own remote repository (on GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket/Gitea/...)

And on Foo, you can then type:

```
git rm Bar1/Folder2
git rm Bar2/Folder2

git submodule add /url/remote/Folder2 Bar1/Folder2
git submodule add /url/remote/Folder2 Bar2/Folder2

git commit -m "Replace Folder2 by submodules"
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand, Folder 2 is not (and will not be) its own repository. Bar/Folder 1 is the git repository (which is done remotely). Folder 2 is a custom folder. The point of doing it at Foo is in fact to avoid what you are stating: create a repository for each Folder 2. I want 1 repository which contains all Folder 2s (which each have unique content)

Comment: @AramPapazian " Folder 2 is not (and will not be) its own repository." and ". I want 1 repository which contains all Folder 2s (which each have unique content": so you still want a separate repository from Foo? But with multiple Folder2 in it?

Comment: No, Foo is not currently a repository. Like I said, I'm trying to turn Foo into a repository in order for it to be its own separate repository which contains the different Folder 2s in it. (Bar 1 and Bar2 are the current existing repositories which only track the Folder 1s)

Comment: @AramPapazian "where Bar 1 and Bar 2 are the same git repo ": how can they be in the same repository, and yet Foo is not that repo?

Comment: They are the same repo as in they are both cloned from the same repo.

Comment: @AramPapazian So if you were to turn Foo as a Git repository, you would need to reference that same repo as a submodule, declared twice (once for Bar1, once for Bar2), but for two different branches: One branch for the first content of Folder2, another branch for the second content of Folder2. Or, if you want those Folder2 content to be in their own repo, then Bar repo would need to reference Folder2 repo as a submodule (again I would recommend two different branches of Bar repo, in order to reference as a submodule two different references of Folder2 new repo)

Comment: Oh! I think I get what you're saying. Make 2 different branches (one for Bar 1 and one for Bar 2) and include Folder 2 in those branches? But then if I make changes to folder 1 in any of those branches then integrating them into the main "Bar" repo would be difficult because now I have to not include Folder 2 somehow even though I'd have to take it out of .gitignore... This still sounds like I need to create a repo for each of the two Folder 2s (in the form of branches). The whole point is to *avoid* this.